# Declaration of App\Http\Requests\Comment\CreateRequest::authorize() should be compatible with App\Http\Requests\Request::authorize()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-request

Hello im creating i comment system for my laravel app but i get this error when i try to comment.. basically when a user is not logged in and he tries to comment and submit it, it should redirect him to the login page, so my CreateRequest file is this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests\Comment;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;
use App\Repositories\Image\ImageRepository;

class CreateRequest extends Request {
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @param ImageRepository $image
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize(ImageRepository $image) {
        $image = $image->getById($this->route('id'))->first();
        if (!$image) {
            return false;
        }
        return auth()->check();
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules() {
        return [
            'comment' => ['required', 'min:2'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function forbiddenResponse() {
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }
}
```

and my `App\Http\Requests\Request` file is this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

abstract class Request extends FormRequest {
    public function authorize() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

if i remove

```
public function authorize() {
    return true;
}
```

then comments works and if user is not logged in the user gets redirected to the login page but then my login is not working and i get Forbidden when i try to login

im developing my app on top of this project https://github.com/laravelish/EasyAdmin 
Hope someone can help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined an `authorize` method in your abstract Request class:

```
public function authorize() {
    return true;
}
```

Note it doesn't take any parameters. Now if you extend this abstract class (like you are doing with CreateRequest) and you write an `authorize` method, you *must* use the same signature. Specifically: `authorize` can't take any parameters, because it doesn't in the abstract class.

---

If you were to remove the `authorize` method from your abstract class, this specific error would go away. However I'm not sure that would solve your problem. I don't think Laravel provides dependency injection for the `authorize` method, you can't just inject your repository like that.

This is one way to fix both issues:

```
public function authorize() {
    $image = app(ImageRepository::class)->getById($this->route('id'))->first();
    ...
```